# Asking for an English version of a paper

Tags: reference-request, it.information-theory

I have been looking for the paper 
"almost independence and secrecy capacity" by Csiszar. But all I could find was a Russian version published in [Problems of Information Transmission](http://www.mathnet.ru/php/archive.phtml?wshow=paper&jrnid=ppi&paperid=319&option_lang=eng).

I am wondering if anyone here has or knows how to find  this paper in English.

Thanks

Comment: It might be possible to translate the Russian version into English.

Answer (score 4):

The full title of the translation appears to be "Almost independence of random variables and the capacity of a secrecy channel" and it appeared in  *Problems of Information Transmission* **32** (1996), no. 1, 40–47. (Found by searching MathSciNet for author=Csiszar, title=capacity. [Here](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1384930) is the review.)

Problems of Information Translation's online archive only appears to go back to 2001 and googling variants of the title doesn't turn up any copies, so the next step is to get out of your chair and walk to the library. For example, Michigan's library [has all the back issues](http://mirlyn.lib.umich.edu/Record/000640418/Holdings#2) of Problems of Information Transmission.

This answer assumes you are a student at an institution which pays for access to academic databases and has a good library. I do realize that not everyone on this site has these privileges, but I think most of us do, and those of us who do should know how to use them.

Comment: If the OP isn't at such an institution, there's always document delivery/interlibrary loan.

Answer (score 1):

You can also contact the author. See [here](http://www.renyi.hu/~csiszar/).

Answer (score 0):

I do not think this is it, but it might be helpful.

http://wk.baidu.com/view/67ddbc1455270722192ef7d9?pcf=2#page/1/1412878650324

http://academic.research.microsoft.com/Detail?entitytype=2&searchtype=2&id=52866079

http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/c/Csisz=aacute=r:Imre.html

After searching the internet for what you have requested, I can see that it is difficult to find what you are looking for. I did not find it, but here are a few links which might be helpful.